# Got the PHP include path blues. Quick and easy bootstrap?

Tags: php, filepath

I am fairly far into a project, and am having trouble having everything included properly.
I have several files in different directories that need to include the same files, but since some are called via ajax or via includes in different situations, there path varies. I had a php_include path set up via .htaccess, but the testing server I need things set up doesn't run with php commands in the .htaccess! I am trying to figure out a quick way of roping everything together.

I have multiple files all including the same 'project' file that in turn includes functions, etc. I have a $ROOT variable set-up to store the absolute path of my directories, but that's not usable in includes without mucking with the php.ini, which I can't do easily, and it's included afterwards anyway.

I know a little bit about bootstrapping, and I would love to route everything through htaccess, but I don't really have a concept of how to implement something like that really quickly and easily (and would that work for files called through ajax?)

I can't rely on server_document_root because it may need to reside in a subdirectory.

This is not class based, but has value objects for database stuff.. there's the main home.php, view.php etc in the root directory, then a program/ directory with the main scripts and value objects, then utilities and components folders that contain miniature view type classes.

I would redo everything if I had time, but right now I'm trying to figure out a way to have everything just work (preferably without dumping everything into one folder :p)

Comment: Take a look at the [Model View Controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern for your next similar project. You'll thank yourself. [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) is a good MVC framework.

Comment: I have SO many ideas of what I'll do different next time

Comment: take a look at http://cakephp.org its better than Code Igniter

Comment: My plan has kinda been to check out Yii.. I've heard only very good things about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `home.php`, or `view.php` include your "main" file, this will include the rest of your app.

```
require 'base.php';
```

Its ok if `home.php` or `view.php` are in some other directory, just do whatever you need to do in that file to load `base.php` something like this will work the same:

```
require '../base.php';
```

Then in `base.php`

```
$root = dirname(__FILE__);
require $root.'/lib/mylib1.php';
require $root.'/lib/mylib2.php';
```

The `__FILE__` is the full path to the current file, `dirname` gets its directory, then you can write all of your includes/requires relative to the location of `base.php`.

I hope this helps point you in a helpful direction.

Comment: I do have a $root variable already.. it's set manually, so dirname would be an improvement, but it doesn't get picked up when I call files with ajax, in which case the path to base.php is different in different uses of the same file

Comment: Even if you are calling a file via ajax, its filesystem location is going to be the same. `require` and `include` use the filesystem, so it doesn't matter if it has a few different URLs that it is accessible by. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: the ajax file though, if it's in a different directory things will be different *relative* to it, as it's the first php file being loaded. SOunds like I may need to try and separate out the ajaxed files and then include the base, and then the file it used to be.. ?

Comment: It may have a different path to include base but thats not a problem, lets say the path to the ajax file is its as complex as "myapp/lib/handlers/ajax/create.php". Thats ok, because at the top of it you put "require '../../../base.php'" (or whatever you need). Then the `$root` in `base.php` takes over, and is ignoring all of the original lookup information because it only cares about paths relative to the directory that `base.php` is physically in. Then the rest of the php files are included based on `$root`, so the path to the very first file (the ajax) no longer matters.

Comment: I"m only involving relative urls in includes right now bc of 'http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0', and limited php.ini access.

Comment: limited in that I [can't edit php.ini on the host](http://help.justhost.com/questions/76/How+do+I+setup+custom+php.ini+settings%3F) wihtout placing a new file in every directory

Comment: Good, thats exactly how you should have it.

Comment: dirname would be relative then?

Comment: It will end up giving you an absolute location to the directory that "base.php" is in, starting at the root of the filesystem, so on servers I work on, $root ends up being "/var/www/mydomain.com/lib", we append whatever we need to that to include files relative to that location.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3918/discussion-between-ctcherry-and-damon)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for this could be to use a variable set before the file is included. You can then check if this variable is defined, and if it isn't use the path for ajax, instead of the include path.

```
$included = true;
include("ajax_inc.php");
```

Assuming your main files are in / and your ajax files are in /ajax:

```
if (isset($included)) {
    $path = "/";
} else $path = "../";
```

You could also do some checks with getcwd() and chdir()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php